# Request to a IIS server (when ASP NET WebForms + MVC co-exist)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, .net-4.5

Well, there are many questions on SO which proves that you have the possibility to hold both `ASP WebForms` as well as `ASP NET MVC` Applications running together.

*Note:*

In MVC, What happens ? The short answer is `Every requests to the webserver first goes through a`**URLRoutingModule** object which reads the request and performs route-selection (depending upon global.asax file). The **MvcRouteHandler** then handles the controller method invocation.

That is okay.
 All I am trying to understand is what happens when a user sends a request to the browser when the web server contains both Web-Forms as well as an ASP.NET MVC Application.

1. **Who reads the URL and understands whether it is an .aspx extension or it is a request to mvc ?**
2. How exactly the ISAPI.dll function in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually fairly simple: the URLRoutingModule checks the disk to see if there is a physical file which matches the current request URL.  If there is a match, the Routing module assumes that it shouldn't run for this request, and ASP.NET's default behavior is then to look up and invoke the default handler for this extension.  In the case of .aspx, that would be the Web Forms handler.

You can change this via the RouteCollection.RouteExistingFiles property in your RegisterRoutes method.  This property controls whether the Routing module should intercept the request regardless of whether there is a physical file on the hard drive.

Comment: Thanks levi.. that makes sense. But, one another things that's bothering me is this: `What is the exact role of ISAPI dll? and there are many dll's of that kind like ASP.DLL , ASP NET DLL. What they do and what are their specific functions?`. googling makes me more confused. can you kindly explain in simplistic terms like you just did for the above question ?

Comment: Think of isapi.dll, webengine4.dll, and other similar modules as providing the glue necessary for System.Web.dll (which is managed) to communicate with IIS (which is native). They provide the extensibility hooks and the native <-> managed translation that System.Web.dll relies on.  But for the most part it's all just implementation details and ASP.NET developers generally don't need to worry about those modules.

Comment: Thank you.. one happy developer here.. :)

Answer (score 1):

To understand better what happens when a user sends a request to the browser when the web server contains both Web-Forms as well as an ASP.NET MVC Application is by knowing on how ASP.Net runtime perform the Url routing which it is actually done by the ISAPI filter plugin.

Below are the detailed steps for Webform request:

1) When user enter a url like website1.com/page1.aspx in the browser.
2) Browser will send a Get Request to the IIS server asking for Page1.aspx file.
3) Then ISAPI filter is the first process to access the Http data before IIS can start to do anything. Here it act like a router for IIS request.
4) ISAPI filter will then check the url whether the filename has any extension (.aspx) and check whether the (.aspx) extension is mapped to the aspnet_isapi.dll or not.
5) If ".aspx" is mapped, it will invoke the ASP.net UrlRoutingModule and mapped the HttpHandler for ASP.net files.

For MVC request:
1) It follow the same step like webform request until the ISAPI filter found that there is no filename and file extension exist in the Url since MVC Url only contain the controller and action name.
2) All Url need to be mapped to a handler when the request initially received because routing will not work with unmanaged handler request
3) To direct this unmanaged request to managed code, it can be done by setting wildcard mapping to aspnet_isapi.dll for IIS6. For IIS7, we can just set the runAllManagedModulesForAllRequest="True". 
4) Then only ASP.Net UrlRoutingModule will be invoked and try to match the Url with the application defined route.
5) If there is a match, it will direct to HttpHandler of Asp.net MVC framework. But if there is no match, the default Asp.net webform mapping will be used and most likely the request will return a HTTP 404 error result.


For more details you may refer to this web:
[Mixing Web Forms and ASP.NET MVC](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/mixing-web-forms-and-asp.net-mvc/)

[Web Server and ASP.NET Application Life Cycle in Depth](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/121096/Web-Server-and-ASP-NET-Application-Life-Cycle-in-D)